# join a table valued function by passing variable argument in SQL Server 2000

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

I have a table valued function that takes an argument and returns four values. I need to invoke this function for each row in a table using join, but it seems SQL Server 2000 does not allow passing variable argument to a table valued function using joins. I can achieve this using "CROSS APPLY" in SQL Server 2005 or 2008, but is there any workaround for this in SQL Server 2000?

I want to do something like this

```
select t1.val1, f.val2, f.val3, f.val4 
from tbl1 t1 
join dbo.tableFunc(t1.val1) f on t1.val1 = f.val1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says that only constants and @local_variables can be passed to table-valued functions (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)). I cannot see the workaround with UDF.
But I think you can use the body of table-valued function iside of query.